# chart.js 2 - Is it possible to format tick labels with HTML?

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs, chartjs-2.6.0

I have a chart that shows 3 datasets - 2 Line, 1 Bar.

I would like to be able to format the Y-2 axis labels in the screenshot below with HTML to allow me to show the values in each tick as bubbles to match the styling displayed on the line data points. (I am using the datalabels plugin to achieve the data point styling https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels).

In addition to this I would like to have all labels with "XLabelLine1" and "XLabelLine2" to have a line break between them.

Is this possible? From looking at the docs it looks as if the axis labels can only be strings.

[image: 3 dataset chart-js 2 chart with bars and lines]

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the tick labels can only be strings and that the Chart.JS tick labels do not have HTML support. It's likely a plugin would need to be developed for this behavior. Sorry. :)

Comment: do you know if such a plugin exists?

Comment: At the time that I searched there wasn't one, probably with good reason - I imagine adding full HTML support to the tick labels is not easy especially with all the other layout concerns